# Disconnect webcam on click after accessing it through .getUserMedia in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-streaming, getusermedia, mediastream

I'm getting a webcam feed through `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` on button click and passing it to `<video />` via createRef API. I need to turn the feed off (not pause) on the same button click if it's on.

I've tried accessing media tracks like

```
.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
 .then(stream => 
  (this.video.current.srcObject = stream.getTracks()[0].stop))
```

to try stopping them with no luck.

I handle stream on/off via this function:

```
handleClick = () => {
 // accessing webcam feed
 if (!this.state.rec) {
   navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
    .then(stream => (this.video.current.srcObject = stream))
 } else {
  // TODO disconnect webcam feed
 }
};
```

I expect to have a function that disconnects the webcam feed on click if it is live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stopping the tracks is the solution, but you actually need to call that method.  You should also call it on all the tracks, even if you're only expecting one, just in case your constraints weren't met exactly.

```
stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
  track.stop();
});
```

Comment: I stopped streaming webcam feed via `this.state.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());` using mediaStream that I put into state on feed init.
While it does cut stream, `<video />` contains a still image of the last frame of the feed. I tried clearing it out via `this.setState({ rec: !this.state.rec, stream: {} }, () => {this.video = null;});` with no luck. Is this an actual API behavior or this is me doing something wrong?

Comment: @moshyfawn Oh, I misunderstood the purpose of what you wanted to do.  Just get rid of the video element.  You can set `src` to `null` if you want, but there are some caveats.  It's probably best just to destroy the element and make a new one later if you need one.  The main reason for calling `.stop()` is to release the webcam so that it isn't stuck on if you're not using it.